# Delay Gestures in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, gesture

I'm creating a complex view that contains a ScrollView with draggable elements in it. I use DragGesture() for each element to implement dragging.

### My Problem

Whenever I touch down an element, its DragGesture will be activated immediately and the ScrollView will not be scrolled when the touch is moved.

### My Goal

I would like to add a time delay (say 1 second) for each DragGesture, such that when the user moves his touch on an element within that time, the ScrollView will be scrolled, but when he touch down an element for that time then move his touch, the element will be dragged.

Comment: You need sequence of long press gesture and drag gesture as, for example, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524230/12299030 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723144/12299030

Comment: Your solution is for handling multiple gestures for one view. In my case, I have two views above each other and both of them have the same DragGesture, but acts differently for each view.

Comment: putting .onTapGesture { } right before the .gesture modifier will delay the .gesture for 1 second.
See: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/a-guide-to-delaying-gestures-in-scrollview/6005

Comment: Thank you Mikael,  such a strange hidden feature to have. I was wondering why it was so slow!

Comment: I just wrestled this and came up with a solution that involves using a button style in combination with other gestures to cover as many cases as possible. You can find it here: https://danielsaidi.com/blog/2022/11/16/using-complex-gestures-in-a-scroll-view